# Pass NOTHING in method vb.Net which is equivalent to NULL in bit Datatype

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a dropdown ddlFlag - Boolean type which holds data:

```
.Items.Insert("0", NewListItem("Any", Nothing))
.Items.Insert("1", NewListItem("Yes", 1))
.Items.Insert("2", NewListItem("No", 0))
```

This dropdown will display data where

1. If flag is Yes - it will display data which is Not NULL
2. If Flag is No - it will display data which is NULL
3. If Flag is Any - it will display data with is both NULL and NOT NULL

My Method is:

```vb
Function DisplayData(ByVal Flag AS Object)
    Dim SqlCommand as String = "dbo.uspDisplayData"
    Dim params() as SQLClient.SqlParameter = {
        New SqlParameter(@Flag, Flag) ' issue is here, how to pass NULL to flag in SQL Execute procedure
    }
    Return Ado.ExecuteDataSet(db,SqlCommand,params)
End Function
```

In stored procedure, this Flag datatype is BIT and is initialized to NULL that is:

```
@flag =  NULL
```

Now question is: By default in VB, Nothing is False
How can I pass NULL from VB code to SQL stored procedure so it will fetch data as NULL and display all (Yes and NO Options both)?

Comment: To pass a SQL `NULL` value, use `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main mistake is here:

```
ByVal Flag AS Object
```

19 times out of 20, if you're using `Object` as the data type in .Net you've made a BIG mistake. In this case, the variable for the `@Flag` parameter with the stored procedure has a specific type (bit), and you should use a matching type for the method argument.

Therefore if we want to use this with an SQL `bit` type that allows NULL values, we start from `Boolean`. Then we also remember the default (`Nothing`) value for a normal Boolean is just `False`; there is no third NULL state. So we actually want a `Nullable(Of Boolean)` (ie: `Boolean?`).

Fix this, so the method expects a `Boolean?`, and you'll likely get a compile error, where you need to create the right item from the selected ddl value. Fix the compile error so you first create and pass a nullable `Boolean?` to the method, and then we can also fix the method to use an SQL `DBNull.Value` when needed, like so:

```vb
Function DisplayData(ByVal Flag AS Boolean?) As DataSet
    Dim SqlCommand as String = "dbo.uspDisplayData"
    Dim params() as SQLClient.SqlParameter = {
        New SqlParameter("@Flag", SqlDbType.Bit) 
    }
    params(0).Value = If(Flag.HasValue, Flag.Value, DBNull.Value)

    Return Ado.ExecuteDataSet(db,SqlCommand,params)
End Function
```

Note the `As DataSet` at the end of the method definition. I had to guess the type, but the main thing is the complaint about `Object` applies as much to your function definitions as with anywhere else. In fact, this also implies you have not turned on `Option Strict`, which is a *major code smell.*

---

As a side note, it's not good to let ADO.Net infer the parameter types unless you're very sure of what you have. The inference process is *not perfect*, and some of the common ways it's gets things wrong have HUGE performance implications: the kind of thing that takes queries that should run effectively instantly to instead need over a minute, or queries that should run in several seconds or a minute to taking nearly an hour.

The SQL type inference does work well enough for most common situations, and even when its wrong you'll still at least get the right results. But those wrong queries can really be slow if you're not careful. It also just happens to be the case that having a method where the parameters come in as `Object` types is one of the things that makes it more likely for ADO.Net to make a mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get dbnull.value will work in Sqlparameters. What should I use in drop-down then? .Items.insert(0, NewListItem(“Any”, Nothing)

Comment: @smc You'll need some code _before you call the method_ to check the selected value and create your `Boolean?`

Comment: The line `params(0).Value = If(Flag.HasValue, Flag.Value, DBNull.Value)` will not compile with `Option Strict On` and `Option Strict` should pretty much always be `On`. Like the C# ternary operator, the VB `If` operator is basically generic, meaning that the last two arguments have to be the same type (or one assignable to the type of the other) so the operator returns that type. For that line to compile, one or both of those arguments would have to be cast as type `Object`, e.g. `params(0).Value = If(Flag.HasValue, Flag.Value, CObj(DBNull.Value))`.

Comment: @smc, your list item values should be `True`, `False` and `Nothing`, so the corresponding property would have to be either type `Object` or type `Boolean?` in order to store all three options. If you get the value as a `Boolean?` then you can pass it to the method in the answer as is. If you get it as an `Object` reference, which seems more likely, then you'll need to cast as type `Boolean?` in order to pass it to that method. All three of those values can be cast that way successfully.

Comment: BTW, you can also use the simpler `If` operator with two parameters here: `params(0).Value = If(Flag, CObj(DBNull.Value))`. For those unaware, the three-parameter version is equivalent to `x ? y : z` in C# while the two-parameter version is equivalent to `x ?? y`.